# See the process of creating a taxonomy and tell me where I made a mistake

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, pagination

Now I will acquaint you with the process of creating a taxonomy and the appearance of an error in the pagination of posts for a certain category of created custom taxanomy.

**Step 1:** Register custom post type

```
register_post_type('product', [
    'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'meta', 'excerpt'],
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => [
        'name' => 'Products',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new product',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit product',
        'all_items' => 'All Products',
        'singular_name' => 'Product'
    ],
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio'
]);
```

**Step 2:** Register taxonomy for `product` post type:

```
register_taxonomy('product_category', 'product', [
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'singular_name' => 'Category',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product_category'),
    'query_var' => true
]);
```

---

Then I created a **page template** with name **[shop_categories_page.php](https://3v4l.org/XONEE)** to display the created taxanomy items (categories). I can see all categories with url: **http://siteurl.com/categories**

---

Then I created a wordpress taxonomies template for show category items with file name **[taxonomy-product_category.php](https://3v4l.org/vQ9f4)**

---

URL for categories item will be **http://siteurl.com/product_category/itemname**. When I paginate all posts by current item from url **return error not found 404**. Pagination url will be **http://siteurl.com/product_category/itemname/page/2**. You can see all my files **[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oK1_XWOpsERiRI7pm2KqGeD6W_8OHuXA)**

---

**How can be solved my problem with pagination?**

Comment: Your code works for me in twentyseventeen. Maybe you haven't updated your permalinks, or another piece of code is creating a conflict.

Comment: Why do you create a new query for product posts in your taxonomy template? WordPress already creates the main query for you, pagination is based on those results, not your custom query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this:

```
$searchProductsByCategory = [
   'posts_per_page'      => 1,
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'orderby'             => 'id',
   'tax_query' => [
       [
           'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
           'terms'    => get_queried_object_id()
       ]
   ]
];

$foundProducts = new WP_Query($searchProductsByCategory);
```

The whole point of `taxonomy-product_category.php` is that posts for the current category *have already been queried*. This is why `get_queried_object_id()` is already the correct category, and why `queried` is in past tense.

When you want to display the posts for the current category/post type/archive inside the relevant template from the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) you need to use the main loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Whenever you're viewing the latest posts, a single post, a single page, posts in a taxonomy term, search results or a date archive, WordPress automatically queries the posts and you display them with the main loop.

This is the only reason the template hierarchy works. How could a custom taxonomy fall back to `index.php` when `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` doesn't exist if they required different queries? It's because they *aren't* separate queries, they're the main query.

Comment: Sorry for the minor rant at the end there, but several times a week somebody asks why pagination isn't working and it's because they've done an unnecessary custom query.

Comment: Thank you for your sincere response, Mr. @Jacob Peattie. This was for me a great lesson in the process of teaching wordpress. As a beginner, it was not clear to me so, if you did not answer the question. That's why a programmer needs logic. Thank you again for your reply.